# mysql select query result is null so how can i return default value in php

Tags: php, opencart

Facing the following error

> Error: Notice: Undefined index: id in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mks/opencart-1.5.6.1/upload/admin/controller/catalog/vendhqbridge.php on line 120

Relevant code:

```
//check for existing 'VendHQ_id' on  DB's product table

function checkVendHQid($flagChk)
{
$rs = $this->db->query("SELECT vendhq_id as id FROM ".DB_PREFIX."vendhq_product WHERE vendhq_id = '".$flagChk."'");

     $rowRsl=-1;
     if($rs===null)
    {
        $rowRsl = -1;
    }
    else
    {
       if($rs->row["id"] == $flagChk  )
       {
           $rowRsl = 1;
       }
    }

    return $rowRsl;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Vikas Umrao and shadyyx, you should change the query and the if condition as below:

**Change:**

```
 $rs = $this->db->query("SELECT vendhq_id as id FROM ".DB_PREFIX."vendhq_product WHERE vendhq_id = '".$flagChk."'");

 $rowRsl=-1;
 if($rs===null)
```

**To:**

```
 $rs = $this->db->query("SELECT vendhq_id as id FROM ".DB_PREFIX."vendhq_product WHERE vendhq_id = '".$this->db->escape($flagChk)."'");

 $rowRsl=-1;
 if(!$rs->num_rows){
```

Have a nice day !!

Answer (score 5):

Put a space after `FROM`

```
$rs = $this->db->query("SELECT vendhq_id as id FROM ".DB_PREFIX."vendhq_product WHERE vendhq_id = '".$flagChk."'");
```

Comment: Also it would be good if the `$flagChk` would be escaped: `$this->db->escape($flagChk)`.